# jQuery registration page not submitting

Tags: jquery, forms, click, registration

When I submit the form for second time it's not getting submitted

```
<div class="wrapper">

        <div class="formelement">

            <label for="fname">Email</label>

            <input type="text" id="Email" name="Email">

        </div>

        <div class="formelement">

            <label for="phoneno">Phone Number</label>

            <input type="text" id="phoneno" name="phoneno">

        </div>

        <div class="formelement">

            <label for="password">Password</label>

            <input type="text" id="password" name="password">

        </div>

        <div class="formelement">

            <label for="confirmpassword">Confirm Password</label>

            <input type="text" id="confirmpassword" name="confirmpassword">

        </div>

        <input id="submitbutton" type="submit">

    </div>

<script>

        var errormessage = "";

        var missingfield = "";

        function isEmail(email) {

        var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;

        return regex.test(email);

        }

        

        $("#submitbutton").click(function(){

            if($("#Email").val() == ""){

                missingfield += "<p>Email not filled</p>";

            }

            if($("#phoneno").val() == ""){

                missingfield += "<p>Phone number not filled</p>";

            }

            if($("#Password").val() == ""){

                missingfield += "<p>Password not filled</p>";

            }

            if($("#ConfirmPassword").val() == ""){

                missingfield += "<p>Password not filled</p>";

            }

            if(isEmail($("#Email").val()) == false){

                errormessage += "<p>Email id is not valid</p>";

            }

            if($.isNumeric($("#phoneno").val()) == false){

                errormessage += "<p>Phone number is not valid</p>"; 

            }

            if($("#password").val() != $("#confirmpassword").val()){

                errormessage += "<p>Password does not match</p>";

            }

            if(errormessage == ""){

                $("#success").html("You are registered")

            }

            else{

                $("#errors").html(errormessage + missingfield);

            }

        });

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [event.preventDefault()](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) , or you can use onsubmit event for your form not for the button

example  where `myform` is your form ID [Live test](https://jsfiddle.net/Lkmau1sv/) :

```
$("#myform").on( "submit", function( event ) {
```

or for your current code :

```
<script>

        var errormessage = "";

        var missingfield = "";

        function isEmail(email) {

        var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;

        return regex.test(email);

        }

        

        $("#submitbutton").click(function(event){

  event.preventDefault();

            if($("#Email").val() == ""){

                missingfield += "<p>Email not filled</p>";

            }

            if($("#phoneno").val() == ""){

                missingfield += "<p>Phone number not filled</p>";

            }

            if($("#Password").val() == ""){

                missingfield += "<p>Password not filled</p>";

            }

            if($("#ConfirmPassword").val() == ""){

                missingfield += "<p>Password not filled</p>";

            }

            if(isEmail($("#Email").val()) == false){

                errormessage += "<p>Email id is not valid</p>";

            }

            if($.isNumeric($("#phoneno").val()) == false){

                errormessage += "<p>Phone number is not valid</p>"; 

            }

            if($("#password").val() != $("#confirmpassword").val()){

                errormessage += "<p>Password does not match</p>";

            }

            if(errormessage == ""){

                $("#success").html("You are registered")

            }

            else{

                $("#errors").html(errormessage + missingfield);

            }

        });

    </script>
```